# Deploying .Net 6.0 application - 500 Server Error

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

When I run the application directly on the server through(localhost:5000) the application is working smoothly. But when I access the site through IIS url and I try(the login form is displayed) to login I get 500 error without further details(The header is displayed, it's not blank page).I thought if I build into development mode I will get extra info,however, that was not the case.

```
Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: 00-b9cc573b740759faf05259764b4af1db-d7b311e682df5b97-00

Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.

The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users. For local debugging, enable the Development environment by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development and restarting the app.
```

[image]

Web Console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Application:

- .Net 6.0
- MVC

Server:

- Windows Server 2022
- IIS 10

Comment: Have you instaled Hosting Bundle 6 ? Also iis rewrite module

Comment: Yes, both of them.

Comment: Have you given permission to pointed path?  Can you check windows even log ? Another thing hosting bundle and the URL rewrite should be installed after IIS installed